# Spring Boot - avoid concurrent write access in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, transactions

I have a project with few thousands people.
People can create user account, and then driver account assigned to one user.

The problem is some user add more than one driver account to one user account, even if i have a function which check if user already has driver.

The problem is users run endpoint addDriver at the same time, and function which is checking if driver was added does not keep up[image]

```
 @Transactional
public Boolean addBasicDriver(DriverBasicRequest driverBasicRequest,UserEntity user){
    // Check if user  already has driver account
    if(userService.hasDriver(user.getId())==true)
        return false;
    // Create driver
  adding driver to database...
    return true;
}
```

I tried to add word @transactional so this method will end before other starts but is seems that this is not working.
Basicly what i want to do to  is to run this endpoints in queue, so if someone run endpoint add driver at same time, then first "shoot on server" is beaing done all, and after that second "shoot on server" is being done. So user want be able to add two drivers to one user account. How to do it?

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357006/spring-boot-how-to-avoid-concurrent-access-to-controller helps you. The root problem is more or less the same - concurrent write access.

Comment: What about changing the scope of the bean where you define the `addBasicDriver` method. Change from the `singleton` to `request`