# Users queue on database. How to stop doubles?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

This is part of code, where users try to modificate database. It's would be smart code, but sometimes users take same rows on table and edit it. How I can stop it?

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editFop(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
    if (!fopRepo.existsById(id)) return "fops";
    Optional<Fop> editPost = fopRepo.findById(id);

    List<Fop> res = new ArrayList<>();
    editPost.ifPresent(res::add);
    Fop fop = res.get(0);
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if(fop.getIdManager() == 0) {
        fop.setIdManager(user.getId());
        fopRepo.save(fop);

... other code
```

Comment: Use `HashMap<K,V>` instead of `List<>` to remove duplicates

Comment: Do you have some error? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358410/3957754) should help you. Share us if it helped you