# Syncronize multiple API REST calls spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency

I need to call a REST API to update a number in database at the same time get the new number generated and return the value, if 2 people call the same endpoint at the same time I don't want the API to return the same value bc of the calls at the same time, I would like that the second call waits for the first call to be finished and so on if there are more than one call.
Hope you understand.
It is like a pile, How can I do it?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358410/10909386

Comment: have you trid to use synchronized key word?